# required field error message

Tags: php

I'm using this piece of code to display an error when the field is left empty but it just returns me to the location.

```
$err = array();
if(empty($native) )
{
$err[] = "ERROR - Enter Native Language";
//header("Location: language.php?msg=$err");
//exit();

 if(!empty($err))  {
   echo "<div class=\"msg\">";
  foreach ($err as $e) {
    echo "* $e <br>";
    }
  echo "</div>";    
   }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: get rid of that bracket if(empty($native) )

Comment: the end one? then I have an open bracket left?

Comment: Is your code all on 1 page? I got confused when you commented out the header but also mentioned it in your question & where is $native set?

Comment: yes it is. The last bit of code is in the HTML part. Native is set `$native = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['native'][$i]);`

Comment: What is the problem now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is up with the square bracket? if(empty($native **]**))

You also need to reference the `$err` array element with an index.

This should work

```
$err = array();
if(empty($native))
{
  $err[] = "ERROR - Enter Native Language";
  header("Location: language.php?msg=$err[0]");
  ...
```

Also, its a good idea to url encode your strings as @Lawrence suggested :)

Comment: Even if i put something in  now it gives me an error. How can I redirect to `header("location: myaccount.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']. "");
 exit();'` when something is entered

Comment: `header("Location: myaccount.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']);` is a valid statement and should work, given `$_SESSION['user_id']` is holding a valid query string value.